# Sinatra Display CSV entries

Tags: ruby, csv, sinatra, erb

How do I display data from a csv file into a Sinatra-App?

> Sinatra:

```
csv = CSV.read(data.csv)
csv.each do |entry|
 @output = "#{entry[1]},#{entry[4]}:#{entry[0]}"
end
```

> Erb:

```
<%= @data %>
```

Which displays only the last row of the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to move the `for` loop to the template file.

In sinatra

```
@csv_data = CSV.read(data.csv)
```

In erb

```
<% @csv_data.each do |entry| %>
  <%= entry[1] %>,<%= entry[4] %>:<%= entry[0] %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

With this code :

```
csv = CSV.read(data.csv)
csv.each do |entry|
 @output = "#{entry[1]},#{entry[4]}:#{entry[0]}"
end
```

You iterate over all csv rows.

For each row, the block defines the `@output` variable.

After the first csv line, the code just keeps on overriding the `@output_variable`.

## Possible solution

You need [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-map), not [each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-each).

```
csv = CSV.read(data.csv)
@data = csv.map do |entry|
  "#{entry[1]},#{entry[4]}:#{entry[0]}"
end
```

You can then use

```
<%= @data %>
```

in your views. `@data` is now an array of strings, with one string for each csv row.